# Meaning of phrase "Hai do do?"

Tags: expressions, spoken-language

When we were in Japan in July I kept hearing shopkeepers say something like "hai dodo" when I went in or even passed by the shop.  I never asked anyone there, but am curious as to the meaning.

Comment: Any chance it could have been "Mai do, mai do"?

Answer (score 5):

They were presumably saying "hai, douzo", which literally means something like "yes, go ahead" but is used to mean something more like "please come in" in this situation.

Comment: It also means "here you go."